# Can I safely do inference from another thread while training the network?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, tensorflow

I have several threads that either update the weights of my network or run inference on it. I use the `use_locking` parameter for the optimizer to prevent concurrent updates of the weights.

Inference should always use a recent, and importantly, consistent, version of the weights. In other words, I want to prevent using a weight matrix for inference for which some of the elements are already updated but others are not.

Is this guaranteed? If not, how can I ensure this? There doesn't seem to be a `tf.Lock` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Do your inference calls need to be on an up-to-date version of the graph? If you don't mind some delay, you could make a copy of the graph by calling sess.graph.as_graph_def on the training thread, and then create a new session on the inference thread using that graph_def periodically.

Comment: Am I concluding correctly from your answer that doing inference while training the same graph can cause in using partially updated variables? Inference should use the newest fully updated version of the weights.